# Testing a concrete third-party class with JMock

Tags: java, unit-testing, jmock

I have class with a forwarding method `foo`:

```
void foo( Concrete c, String s ) { c.bar( s ); }
```

I wish to test whether `foo` does, in fact, forward. Unfortunately for me, `Concrete` is a class in a third-party library, and is a concrete type, not an interface. Thus I must use `ClassImposteriser` in JMock to mock `Concrete`, so in my test case, I do this:

```
@Test
public final void testFoo() {
   Mockery context = new JUnit4Mockery() {{
      setImposteriser(ClassImposteriser.INSTANCE);
   }};

  final Concrete c = context.mock(Concrete.class);
  final String s = "xxx" ;

  // expectations
  context.checking(new Expectations() {{

     oneOf (c).bar(s); // exception gets thrown from here
  }});


  new ClassUnderTest.foo( c, s );
  context.assertIsSatisfied();
```

}

Unfortunately, `Concrete.bar` in turn calls a method that throws. That method is final, so I can't override it. Further, even if I comment out the line `new ClassUnderTest.foo( c, s );`, the exception is thrown when JMock sets up exceptions, not when `foo` is called.

So how can I test that method `ClassUnderTest.foo` does forward to `Concrete.bar`?

Edit:
Yes, bar is final.

My solution, which is *not* a general one, was to use a "Tester" class in the third-party library to correctly set up `Concrete`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not clear from the question text if Concrete.bar() is final or if Concrete.somethingElse() is final and called from Concrete.bar().

If Concrete.bar() **is not final**, create a hand-written stub for Concrete like this:

```
public class ConcreteStub extends Concrete
{
    public int numCallsToBar = 0;
    @Override
    public void bar(String s) { numCallsToBar++; }
}
```

and in your test code:

```
ConcreteStub c = new ConcreteStub();
foo(c,"abc");
assertEquals(1,c.numCallsToBar);
```

If Concrete.bar() **is final**, it is more complicated and the answer depends on the complexity of Concrete and your project's use of the Concrete class.  If your use of Concrete is simple enough, I would consider wrapping Concrete in an interface ([Adapter Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern)) that you can then mock out easier.

Benefits to the Adapter Pattern solution: Possibly clarify behavior by naming interface after your project's use of Concrete.  Easier to test.

Drawbacks to the Adapter Pattern solution: Introduces more classes with possibly little benefit to production code.   I don't know what Concrete does and it may not be practical to wrap Concrete in an interface.

Answer (score 4):

See http://www.jmock.org/mocking-classes.html for info about mocking classes and how to bypass final limitations.

Comment: Could you expand this link-only answer a bit? I didn't flag, because I see you're still an active user and this is an old answer, but some more explanation would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If a method is final then we can't do much about it. If this is a third-party library, then we would consider wrapping it in a veneer layer and mocking *that*, then doing integration tests to test against the library. There are other frameworks that will mock locked-down code, but we don't support it because we don't think it's a great idea.

Answer (score 0):

Use a more capable mocking tool, such as [JMockit](http://code.google.com/p/jmockit). Your test could then be written as:

```
@Test
public void testFoo(final Concrete c)
{
  final String s = "xxx";

  new Expectations() {{
    c.bar(s);
  }};

  new ClassUnderTest().foo(c, s);
}
```

For JMockit, it makes no difference if `Concrete` is an interface, a final class, an abstract class, or whatever. Also, there is no need to use `@RunWith`, extend a base test class, or call any method like `assertIsSatisfied()`; it's all done automatically, in a transparent way.